# How to zip stdin along with stdout line by line

Tags: bash, shell

I have a simple command (`my_cc`) that computes the number of characters in each line.

This command yields 5, 6, 7, and 8 for `text` file respectively.

```
$ cat text
12345
123456
1234567
12345678

$ cat text | ./my_cc 
5
6
7
8
```

My question is how to zip stdin along with stdout line by line like (without multiple processes):

```
$ cat text | some_magic_command with my_cc
12345 5
123456 6
1234567 7
12345678 8
```

A possible answer is:

```
$ cat text | xargs -I {} bash -c "echo {} | ./my_cc | sed 's/^/{} /g'"
12345 5
123456 6
1234567 7
12345678 8
```

But this invokes processes of `my_cc` as the number of lines in `text`.

I can not use this command because `my_cc` is too heavy to run for each line. Also I can not modify the `my_cc`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`paste`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/paste.html):

```
paste -d ' ' text <(./my_cc < text)
```

This puts a space between each line of `text` and the output of your command.

If you have a shell that doesn't support process substitution, you can read from standard input instead:

```
./my_cc < text | paste -d ' ' text -
```

Answer (score 1):

If

1. `my_cc` doesn't buffer its output, but writes a line of output immediately after receiving each line of input (most commands don't do that), and
2. your text doesn't come from a file but is e.g. generated from another command on the fly,

you can do the following:

```
my_cc() {
    perl -nle 'BEGIN { $| = 1 } print length'
}

coproc my_cc
while read -r; do
    printf '%s ' "$REPLY"
    printf '%s\n' "$REPLY" >&${COPROC[1]}
    read -r <&${COPROC[0]}
    printf '%s\n' "$REPLY"
done < <( echo '12345
123456
  .  
1234567
12345678' )

exec {COPROC[0]}<&- {COPROC[1]}>&-
wait $COPROC_PID
```

Output:

```
12345 5
123456 6
  .   5
1234567 7
12345678 8
```

Note:

Condition #1 is essential. If `my_cc` buffers its output, this code will deadlock.

Condition #2 is not strictly required. You could easily run this code on a file (`while read -r; do ... done < sometextfile`), but a file can be read multiple times, so simpler solutions (that don't require condition #1) are possible.

Explanation:

- `my_cc` is defined as a shell function to stand in for your actual command. It does what you described (prints the length of each line), but `$| = 1` deserves comment: This statement enables autoflush mode on the currently selected output handle (which defaults to stdout), i.e. output is written immediately after each `print` command.
- `coproc` is a bash built-in command that runs the specified command in the background (as a co-process).
- The `while read -r` loop reads input line by line from another command (here played by `echo '...'`).
- Each line read (`$REPLY`) is first printed followed by a space, then sent to the coprocess.
- Then we read a single line of output from the coprocess and print it followed by a newline.
- At the end we close the file descriptors of our coprocess and wait for it to terminate.